# jqgrid - triggering loading... message when overriding ajax default options

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The loading... message is not being displayed when I provide ajaxGridOptions to the .jqgrid.defaults. I need to have this functionality to handle session time outs for my ajax requests. How do I trigger loading... message in this case and also hide it on completion of the request...

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    //altRows : true
    ajaxGridOptions : {
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            setAjaxHeader(xhr);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            handleAjaxSessionTimeOuts(xhr);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleAjaxExceptions(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```

I think we can do something like $(".loading").css("display", "block"); but I am not sure which is the right place to do. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting .loading class in beforeSend and hiding it in complete method. If any one has a better solution, please let me know. Thanks...

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    //altRows : true
    ajaxGridOptions : {
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            setAjaxHeader(xhr);
            $(".loading").css("display", "block");
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            handleAjaxSessionTimeOuts(xhr);
            $(".loading").css("display", "none");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleAjaxExceptions(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```